# Getting input inside dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeater

I have this dynamic table:

```
<table id="monthProd" class="tableList">
            <tr>
                <td id="Th1" width="65px">
                </td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptTech" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <th>
                            <asp:Label ID="techTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sName") %>' techID='<%# Eval("iCodigo") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </th>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label ID="capacidadeTitle" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Planning_DailyPlan_Total %>"></asp:Label>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptClient" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptClient_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <asp:Label ID="clientTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sName") %>' customerID='<%# Eval("sCNPJ") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </th>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptValuesGerais" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Text="0" onchange="changeTotal();"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblValueTotal1" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Planning_DailyPlan_Total %>"></asp:Label>
                </th>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptValuesFooter" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblValueTotal2" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEndLine" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Now when i change a value with onchange event, i need to add all the values ​​of the row to the last "lblValueTotal1" in the row...
I need a script to do this, but i dont know much about javascript, all the things that a tryed cant give me the the exact value of the td =/

You can see it in here: 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not familiar with the asp tag, but if it has a numerical value, you can use the jQuery ID selector and val() method like so:

$("#lblValueTotal1").val() = 9000;

If that doesn't have the right data type, possibly the  might contain it, for which you could make an ID. 
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: cant be done this way... i cant access the element by the id, cause of the repeater change it when he generate...

Answer (score 0):

Ok u must do something like this...

```
function myfunction
{
 var value_one = document.getElementbyId('firstvalue').value;
 var value_two = document.getElementbyId('secvalue').value;
 var value_third = document.getElementbyId('thirdvalue').value;
 var total = value_one + value_two + value_third;
 document.getElementById.value = total;
}
```

in onchange Event